# Matlab to C# code translation and matrix/array

Tags: c#, arrays, matlab, matrix, translation

Im rewriting matlab code to C#. I have no idea about programming in matlab and I can't understand this part:

```
d9=[d9 d8];
d10=d9(:,2:10);
d5=[d6 d10 d7];
```

Variables d6, d7, d8 and d9 are 2-dimensional arrays.

Full Matlab code is here: [link to codeforge.com](http://www.codeforge.com/read/74065/hopfield.m__html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I have no idea about programming in matlab and I can't understand this part"*

**a) `d9=[d9 d8];`**

will concatenate the matrix `d9` and `d8` and store result in `d9`. Other way is that it just append matrix `d8` to `d9`

Example :

```
>> a=[1 2;3 4]

a =

     1     2
     3     4

>> b=[5 6;7 8]

b =

     5     6
     7     8

>> a=[a b]

a =

     1     2     5     6
     3     4     7     8
```

**b) `d10=d9(:,2:10);`**

`:` is [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)  extensively used for vector manipulation, sub-scripting and creating for loops iterator

Here,

second subscript `2:10` means the columns number 2 3 4...10 in `d9`

first subscript `:` all rows in `d10`

So `d10`  is assigned by all elements in column 2 to 10 from all rows of `d9`.

Example :

```
>> c=a(:,2:4)

c =

     2     5     6
     4     7     8
```

**c) `d5=[d6 d10 d7];`**

Again similar to first one, concatenates matrices `d6` `d10` and `d7` and assign the result to `d5`.

Comment: That explains everything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

not yet able to comment directly under an answer but I think there is a typo in P0W's answer.

It should state:

" first subscript : all rows in *d9* " (emphasis added) instead of " first subscript : all rows in d10 "

The rest of the answer is correct but just in case it confuses somebody unfamiliar with Matlab...